# How to test a reset password request with spring boot and postman?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm currently working on a reset password for users and I had a problem testing the method. This is the code below:

```
    @PostMapping("/user/resetPassword")
public GenericResponse resetPassword(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String userEmail) {
    System.out.println("Here we are in the method of the reset *********");
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail1(userEmail);
    System.out.println ( user.getId());
    System.out.println("This is my user"+user);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }
    String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    userService.createPasswordResetTokenForUser(user, token);
    mailSender.send(constructResetTokenEmail(getAppUrl(request), request.getLocale(), token, user));
    return new GenericResponse(messages.getMessage("message.resetPasswordEmail", null, request.getLocale()));
}
```

The problem is in the findByEmail it is not returning the user from the email that I am inserting in the JSON in the Postman payload:

```
User findByEmail(String email);
```

the result of the execution is UserNotFoundException.

Comment: ` userRepository.findByEmail1(userEmail);` Did you create the findByEmail1 method or is it a typo

Comment: This question has very few details to find the actual problem. Have you verified that the user repository is configured correctly? Have you printed the userEmail parameter to make sure it is correct? Why are you calling "findByEmail1" (if your column name is email, usually it would be "findbyEmail")? You can also post your UserRepository class and User entity for getting a solution.

Comment: i have created it and i also tried a typo @TuhinKantiSharma

Comment: @ShankarPS yeah i did it all the email when debugging is seen so it is being passed through the json

Comment: @Ella, may be you can edit your question to add your UserRespository. Currently, your question seems incomplete.